# What does * next to the file name mean in the output of ls?

Tags: ls

I have a doubt related the output of `ll` command.

When, in my shell, I execute the `ll` command I obtain this output:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 andrea andrea 104215 ott 15 15:56 atmosfs*
```

Why I have the `*` next to the file name `atmosfs`? What does it mean?

Comment: it seems to be copy of http://serverfault.com/questions/233468/ubuntu-at-the-end-of-filename

Comment: @dchirikov: It's merely a duplicate, not a copy. (The word "copy" might imply a copy-and-paste of the exact content.)

Comment: sure this is a duplicate, but the question header is much more appropriate as for me: I see the `*` but no `-F` flag passed. So would I never found the answer without such good already asked question. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `*` means the file is executable (permissions-wise).

Your alias probably includes the `-F` option for `ls`, which will add:

- `/` onto directories
- `*` onto files that are executable
- `@` onto symbolic links
- `=` onto sockets
- `|` onto FIFOs (First In First Out, aka Named Pipes)

You'll mostly see the first three in day to day usage.

It's jarring if one is unfamiliar with it, but it's quite a useful option.